# Como obter um único elemento através do array.filter

Tags: javascript

Utilizando [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), seleciono apenas um objeto de `address`, porém seu retorno contém um `array` com índices vazios.

O `array` possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
  {
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "locality"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "New York 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "postalCode"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "Kings, New York, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "locality"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "New York, New York, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "New York, USA",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "formatted_address": "United States",
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "long name",
        "short_name": "short name",
        "types": [
          "country"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
let address = [];

address.push({
  formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['route']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['postalCode']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_1']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "United States",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['country']
  }]
});


let administrative_area_level_1 = address.map((address) => {
  return address.address_components.filter((elem, i, array) => {
    if (elem.types.includes('administrative_area_level_1')) {
      return elem;
    }
  });
});

console.log(administrative_area_level_1);
```

Após o tratamento, é retornado:

```
[
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [
    {
      "long_name": "long name",
      "short_name": "short name",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1"
      ]
    }
  ],
  []
]
```

Quando o esperado seria:

```
 {
  "long_name": "long name",
  "short_name": "short name",
  "types": [
    "administrative_area_level_1"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Marcelo, na pergunta dás exemplo de somente 1 objeto, mas pode ter mais certo? e pode ter mais que um por cada `address_components`?

Comment: Pode sim, @Sergio. Terminei reduzindo no exemplo utilizado.

Comment: Ok, então a minha resposta deve fazer o que queres. Se quisesses reduzir mais podias usar o `.find` também.

Comment: Sim, tua resposta já direcionou-me a um resultado positivo.

Comment: Ok, mas era isso que demos nas respostas que procuravas ou ainda falta alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let address = [];

address.push({
  formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['route']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['postalCode']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_1']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "United States",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['country']
  }]
});


address.map((address) => {
  return address.address_components.filter((elem, i, array) => {
    if (elem.types.includes('administrative_area_level_1')) {
       administrative_area_level_1 = elem;
    }
  });
});

console.log(administrative_area_level_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro filtrar primeiro pois reduzes logo o tamanho da array para futuro processamento, e depois mapear o que passar o filter.

```js
let address = [];

address.push({
  formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['route']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['postalCode']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['locality']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_2']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "New York, USA",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['administrative_area_level_1']
  }]
});
address.push({
  formatted_address: "United States",
  address_components: [{
    long_name: 'long name',
    short_name: 'short name',
    types: ['country']
  }]
});


let administrative_area_level_1 = address.filter((address) => {
  return address.address_components.find(
    comp => comp.types.includes('administrative_area_level_1')
  );
}).map(address => address.address_components);

console.log(administrative_area_level_1);
```